# How to use subscript in pattern names?

Tags: custom-notation, pattern-matching

For example I want to define a function with parameters σ<sub>x</sub> and σ<sub>y</sub>, that is, the function will be declared as:

```
f[σx_,σy_] := . . .
```

I tried [`Symbolize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) but it doesn't work. How can I use `Subscript` in pattern names?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `Symbolize`, from the `Notation` package following the tutorial as you did.

Then, just take the precaution of writing the pattern with its head explicit, such as:

```
Pattern[xr, _]
```

The problem is that Mathematica can't interpret the short notation for patterns (`xr_` for example) if it has a box structure before the "_"

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by [Rojo](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/109/rojo) in the answer above,

```
xr_
```

can't be interpreted as desired even after `Symbolize` is used, but one doesn't need to write `Pattern` in its `FullForm` to circumvent the problem, actually you just need one more `:` i.e.

```
xr:_
```

Example:

[image]

---

Another work-around is to use my [`allowNonSymbol`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138605/1871). Example:

```
allowNonSymbol[
 f[Subscript[σ, x] _, Subscript[σ, y] _] := Sin[Subscript[σ, x]] + 2^Subscript[σ, y]]

f[a, b]
```

[image]

Comment: I am using mathematica 11.0, and after loading the Notation package and entering Symbolize[<keystrokes>], where <keystrokes> was Shift+_ then Control+_ then Shift +_, I got the error message "Symbolize::noboxtag: The Symbolize boxes Subscript[ _ , _ ] do not have an embedded TemplateBox with tag NotationTemplateTag. The Symbolize statement Symbolize[Subscript[ _ , _ ]] may not have been entered using the palette, or the embedded TemplateBox may have been deleted. The embedded TemplateBox ensures correct parsing and retention of proper styling and grouping information."

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs As mentioned [in the document](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html#20750902): When defining your own notations it is _critically_ important to use the notation templates. So don't type `Symbolize` directly, use the Notation Palette popping up when you execute `<<Notation\``.

Comment: Thanks. I have been looking through the documentation since I posted the comment, and I just now stumbled upon that.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it really saved me.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the input form in the definition

`f[Subscript[σ, x_], Subscript[σ, y_]] := ...`

Comment: CarloB, welcome to the site.  I don't believe this works in the way the OP wants.  It would require entering your values as subscripts to sigma for each argument.