# How to define a function of non-symbol

Tags: functions, function-construction

Using [Displaying index as subscript on output: e.g. C[i] -> C_i with Notation[...] or Interpretation[..]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30884/displaying-index-as-subscript-on-output-e-g-ci-c-i-with-notation-or) I have often ended up wanting to define functions of annotated variables to better match my whiteboard mathematics.  Naively, I would want to do things like:

```
f[z[bar]_] := z[bar]^2;
relativez[z_, z[bar]_] := z / z[bar];
```

However, this doesn't work.    Obviously, I can do things like

```
f[zbar_] := zbar^2;
f[z[bar]]
```

But I would prefer to have it map to my math better if a simple variation of this pattern works.

Comment: Which is more important: the entry of this function definition, or the way the definition displays with e.g. `Definition[f]`?

Comment: If it isn't possible to do both at the same time, then I think that current answer gives a possible tradeoff where I can choose as appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

You are close to the truth

```
f[z_[bar_]] := z[bar]^2;
f[a[b]]
```

> ```
> a[b]^2
> ```

Comment: So close.  Also note that the following works: `f2[z_, z_[bar_]] := z/z[bar]; f2[a, a[bar]]`

Comment: Just a confirmation though, in your original version the following does not work `f[zb]`, presumably because it needs to match a pattern with a `[_]`.  In this sense, I am not getting exactly what I am want (which is `z[bar]` as a complete placeholder on its own.  However, for my purposes this may be sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

This post contains several code blocks, you can copy them easily with the help of [`importCode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/1871).

---

The following is an *attempt* for making a general purpose function for this task:

```
ClearAll[allowNonSymbol]
SetAttributes[allowNonSymbol, HoldAll]
allowNonSymbol[Set[lhs_, rhs_]] := allowNonSymbol[SetDelayed[lhs, #]] &@rhs
allowNonSymbol[func_SetDelayed] := 
  With[{blank = Verbatim[#][___] & /@ (Blank | BlankSequence | BlankNullSequence)}, 
    Module[{newFunc, independentVar}, {newFunc, {independentVar}} = 
        Reap[Hold@func /. 
                var_ (holder : blank) :> 
                  RuleCondition[Sow@HoldPattern@var; Pattern[var, holder]] /. 
              var_ Verbatim[PatternTest][holder : blank, test_] :> 
                
        RuleCondition[Sow@HoldPattern@var; PatternTest[Pattern[var, holder], test]] // 
            Quiet, _, Union[#2] &]; 
      With[{rule = # -> Unique[] & /@ independentVar}, newFunc /. rule // ReleaseHold]]]

allowNonSymbol[func : Function[independentVar_, rhs__]] := 
  With[{rule = # -> Unique[] & /@ Flatten@{independentVar}}, 
    Hold[func] /. rule // ReleaseHold]
```

### Usage

```
Clear[f, relativez]
mid = z[bar]^2;
allowNonSymbol[f[z[bar] _] = mid];
allowNonSymbol[relativez[z_, z[bar] _] := z/z[bar]];
f[3]
(* 9 *)
relativez[2, 3]
(* 2/3 *)
```

`allowNonSymbol` can be used on pure function:

```
sin = allowNonSymbol@Function[b[1], Sin@b[1]];
Sin[2.]
(* 0.909297 *)
```

It can handle `BlankSequence[]`(`__`) and `BlankNullSequence[]`(`___`):

```
Clear[times, join]
allowNonSymbol[times[argu[n] __] := Times[argu[n]]]
times[2, 3, 5]
(* 30 *)
allowNonSymbol[join[lst_, ele[i] ___] := Join[lst, ele[i]]]
join[{3}]
(* {3} *)
```

It can also handle `_h` and `PatternTest`:

```
Clear[f, g]
allowNonSymbol[f[a[2] _Integer] := 2 a[2]]
f[2]
(* 4 *)
f[2.]
(* f[2.] *)
allowNonSymbol[g[a[1] _?NumericQ] := a[1]]
g[3]
Clear[a]; g[a]
(* g[a] *)
```

### Known issue

1. Patterns like `a[1]:{_Integer}` can't be used, and it seems to be impossible to overcome the issue, because *Mathematica* notebook simpliy can't parse the expression:

   ```
        a[1] : {_Integer}
   ```

[image]

2. Patterns like `Pattern[a[1], {_Integer}]` isn't supported yet.

---

BTW, it's worth mentioning that non-symbol can be used as independent variables in `Compile` and `` Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction ``, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163273/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/44890/1871) post for more info. (Since these are advanced topics, I'd suggest not to dive into them if you're not experienced enough. )