# Function definition with sub (super) cripted variables

Tags: functions, custom-notation, subscript

I like using subscripts *a lot*. However, it is regrettably not possible to do, for example:

```
myfunction[Subscript[x,1]_] := Subscript[x,1] +1
```

where instead of the subscript, I would use Ctrl+_ to make the subscript. See below

[image]

Is there a way around this?

Comment: [Don't use `Subscript`. It is evil.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395) Maybe it is `myfunction[x_] := Indexed[x, 1] + 1` what you want...

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32648/1871

Comment: I've added [869](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/869/5478) as a duplicate because the answer is exactly the same if we replace `Module` with `Pattern` name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Mathematica* is a rewrite language. `x_` means "match something and give it the name `x` for rewrite purposes". `Subscript[x,1]_` is meaningless, because `Subscript[x,1]` isn't a symbol.

One way to deal with things like this is to deconstruct them and reconstruct what you want.

```
myfunction[var_Subscript] := Subscript[var[[1]], var[[2]]] + var[[2]]^2
```

The argument pattern here recognizes anything with the head `Subscript`. The function body deconstructs it and reconstructs using both parts of the `Subscript` expression.

```
myfunction[Subscript[x, 2]]
(* 4 + Subscript[x, 2] *)
```

If you only want it to work when the subscript is 1, perhaps the handiest way is to put that in the argument pattern and do your deconstruction there:

```
anotherway[Subscript[x_, 1]] := Subscript[x, 1] + 1
anotherway[Subscript[y, 1]]
(* 1 + Subscript[y, 1] *)
```

You can also do implement this kind of restriction with `Condition`, left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Oh, and yes, subscripts can cause you much confusion unless you **really** understand `Mathematica` as a rewrite language. @Henrik Schumacher@ is right.