# How to convert list of variables x1, x2, x3 ,x4 ... x10 to list of x1_,x2_,x3_..x10_?

Tags: functions, map, pure-function

I'm writing a function where I need to give many inputs. I created a list of variables from Table function.

My aim is to get

```
f[Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[x, 2],Subscript[x, 3]]
```

from table which i create

```
Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 3}]
```

What i need is

```
f @@ Blank /@ {Subscript[x, 1], 
    Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3], 
    Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5], 
    Subscript[x, 6], Subscript[x, 7], 
    Subscript[x, 8], Subscript[x, 9], 
    Subscript[x, 10]}
```

But that is not converting x to x_ . How to get that ?

Comment: try `f @@ (Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], 
    Subscript[x, 3], Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5], 
    Subscript[x, 6], Subscript[x, 7], Subscript[x, 8], 
    Subscript[x, 9], Subscript[x, 10]})` and see [this q/a](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2854/125)

Comment: hi, my aim is to convert all elements in the list  {x1,x2,x3,x4} to {x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_} so that i can send this list to function f[x1_,x2_,x3_,x4_] = Sin[x1 x2 x3 x4]

Comment: I tried what you suggested it is not converting x to x_

Comment: Guammala, try `symbols = Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString@#] &, 5];
ClearAll[f];
f[## & @@ (Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ symbols)] := 
  Evaluate[Sin[Times @@ symbols]];
f[a, b, c, d, e]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear[f, lhs, rhs]

{lhs, rhs} = Transpose@ToExpression[
    {StringJoin["x", #, "_"], StringJoin["x", #]} & /@ 
     Array[ToString, 4]];

Evaluate[f @@ lhs] := Evaluate[Sin[Times @@ rhs]]

f[a, b, c, d]

(*  Sin[a b c d]  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
symbols = Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString@#] &, 5];

ClearAll[f];
f[## & @@ (Pattern[#, Blank[]] & /@ symbols)] := Evaluate[Sin[Times @@ symbols]];

f[a, b, c, d, e]
```

> Sin[a b c d e]

```
f @@ {a, b, c, d, e}
```

> Sin[a b c d e]