# Can you use superscripts as variable and function names?

Tags: functions, pattern-matching, variable-definitions, symbols, custom-notation

I want to express the following function:

$z^{(1)}=w^{(1)}a^{(0)}+b^{(1)}$

I have read in Mathematica documentation that `Symbolize` can be used to define variables with superscripts. I would like to define a function that uses $w^{(1)}$, $a^{(0)}$ and $b^{(1)}$ as dependent variables.

This is what I have tried:

```
<< Notation`
    Symbolize[NotationTemplateTag[z^(1)]]
    Symbolize[NotationTemplateTag[w^(1)]]
    Symbolize[NotationTemplateTag[a^(0)]]
    Symbolize[NotationTemplateTag[a^(1)]]
    Symbolize[NotationTemplateTag[b^(1)]]
```

And then I try to define the variable as:

```
(z^(1))[w^(1)_, a^(0)_, b^(1)_] := w^(1) a^(0) + b^(1)
```

but I get `$Failed`.

Specifically:
[image: Failed function definition]

Is it possible to define a function named with a superscript and having as dependent variables symbols with superscripts? I so, what is not properly done above?

Comment: I suspect that `z^(1)` is interpreted as `Power[z,1]` and simplifying to `z` automatically.  You could try `Trace` and `FullForm`.

Comment: I am actually entering z^(1) using control+^, so that z^(1) shall be theoretically treated as a single symbol. I have attached a screenshot.

Comment: I **strongly** encourage you to use another notation. This may look good, but you are setting yourself up for a lot of unnecessary work and restrictions down the road when you actually have to do any computation on these symbols. The best way is normally indexed variables such as `z[1]` instead.

Comment: Your code gives me `$Failed`. Using the Notations pallete to create the `Symbolize[]` command, I achieved this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnwNr.png -- It seems key here to use `symbol : Blank[]` instead of `symbol_`. I guess the latter is not parsed correctly when `symbol` is a box structure that is supposed to be symbolized.

Comment: (+1) I think the generalized question, How can one use symbols created by the Notation package as pattern names?, is good. I wouldn't be surprised if there's already a similar Q&A on site, given how often the Notation package is used. (Bob Hanlon's answer seems to address output formatting only, which is not the same as input formatting.) I generally avoid programming with the Notation package for the reasons @MarcoB points out. But it does have its uses, which shouldn't be dismissed.

Comment: Found one: Does this answer your question? [How to use subscript in pattern names?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2854/how-to-use-subscript-in-pattern-names)

Comment: To clarify, your `Symbolize[...]` code fails each of the four times.

Comment: @MichaelE2 For Symbolise I had to use the tool palette, just typing the code did not work.
I will check the suggestion on indexed variables, I am pretty new to Mathematica and I am still learning how the different options are and which are the most sensible approaches to use Mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

Format indexed variables

```
(Format[#[n_]] := Superscript[#, Row[{"(", n, ")"}]]) & /@ 
  {z, w, a, b};
```

The function definition is

```
z[1][x_, y_, z_] := x*y + z
```

With your specific arguments

```
z[1][w[1], a[0], b[1]]
```

[image]